# how to use an arabic stemmer on ubuntu

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, arabic, stemming

I'm trying to test out stemming Arabic text using the ISRIStemmer tool but the GNOME terminal doesn't properly render Arabic text which is RTL.

I assume this means I need to have the texts I need in external documents and reference them in the code.

Can any one show me an example of how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Do it exactly like you would do it with English-- just make sure to include `encoding="utf8"` (or whatever encoding you use) in the arguments to `open()`. Plus find a Terminal application and/or editor that displays Arabic properly, so you can see the results. I hear `konsole` can do it; I also know for a fact that "jupyter notebooks" (which run inside a browser) display RTL text correctly. They come with Anaconda Python, if you want to go that route.

Comment: PS. See here on [how to enable Arabic support on gnome terminal](https://gist.github.com/IslamAzab/49428f09cffc4f453be9). If it's really not supported out of the box, that's a bit ridiculous in this day and age. But you'll also need to use the correct encoding (probably UTF-8), other encodings won't work.